# Un-initialize a variable in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, initialization

This is more a theoretical question than a practical one, but I was wondering whether is it possible to un-initialize a variable in C (or C++). So let's say we have the following code:

```
void some_fun()
{
    int a; // <-- Here a is an un-initialized variable, it's value is the value
           // found in the memory at the given location.
    a = 7; // Now I have initialized it 

    // do something with a ... 

    // and here do something again with a that it 
    // will have the same state (ie: indeterministic) as before initialization  
}
```

(No, I don't want to put a random value in `a` because that would be also an initialization, nor 0, because that's a very nice value, ... I just want it to be again in that "I don't know anything about it" stage it was before initializing it).

(Yes I am aware of: [What happens to a declared, uninitialized variable in C? Does it have a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597405/what-happens-to-a-declared-uninitialized-variable-in-c-does-it-have-a-value))

Comment: `a = 7; // Now I have initialized it ` is not initialization. it's assignment.

Comment: when your code reach close bracket } you can consider that local "a" variable will become un-initialized

Comment: You can't do that. Fortunately there is no good reason to do it anyway.

Comment: @ars but after the closing } I cannot access it ... it's out of scope :(

Comment: `a = NULL` should do it well enough? Unless you're thinking about something else. And also, why do you want to do that?

Comment: @juanchopanza That's why I mentioned this to be a theoretical question :)

Comment: `#define UNINITIALIZE(x)`. Now say `UNINITIALIZE(x);`, and afterwards, `x` has an indeterminate value. It is UB to now read from `x`.

Comment: @fritzone, exactly, that's why this is the only variant to "un-initialize" local variable

Comment: Once you have initialized a variable ,There is no way to uninitialized it again.

Comment: You could put another `int a;` inside `{ }` and hope the compiler decides to use the same memory block for it.

Comment: I suggest you do not attempt to write source code that is valid C and C++ simultaneously.

Comment: If you want to do that for performance reasons, the compiler is probably smart enough to recycle variables anyway. Just use another variable.

Comment: @Yann4 Well no, you are most likely setting the int variable to `0` with that.

Comment: You would never be able to observe the effect of "uninitialisation" in a valid program, so I can't see any reason for it to be possible at all.

Comment: @molbdnilo in C++ you can read uninitialized values in certain ways without causing undefined behaviour, so it would actually be possible to observe (e.g. if you make multiple reads of the value and it has different values each time).

Comment: @MattMcNabb Do you have an example of how you could read an uninitialized variable without UB?

Comment: @juanchopanza oops, I was recalling C , not C++. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25074180/is-aa-or-a-a-undefined-behaviour-if-a-is-not-initialized)

Comment: @fritzone -- your question presumes something that is not true. The initial value of an automatic variable is NOT "the value found in memory at the given location", it is "undefined behavior". There is no guarantee of any predictable behavior for an automatic variable that has not had a value assigned to it. So, NO, you cannot "uninitialize" something that has no defined "uninitialized" behavior.

Comment: With some compilers this would be useful, since they may warn when referencing the value of uninitialized variables.  So, eg, when a variable is used (some might say misused) as a "local" in a loop, it can be set to "uninitialized" on exit from the loop to prevent it from being referenced until reinitialized.

Comment: It should be noted that Java and some other languages *require* variables to be initialized before being referenced -- the program cannot be compiled otherwise.  In Java's case this is necessary to maintain the strong typing of the language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `setjmp()` and `longjmp()` to get the behavior you want, with some rearrangement of your code. The code below initializes `a` to 1 so that the print statements do not invoke undefined behavior.

```
jmp_buf jb;

void some_func (void)
{
    int a = 1;

    if (setjmp(jb) == 0) {
        a = 7;

        // do something
        printf("a = %d (initialized)\n", a);

        // use longjmp to make `a` not initialized
        longjmp(jb, 1);
        // NOTREACHED
    } else {
        printf("a = %d (not initialized)\n", a);
    }
}
```

The `longjmp()` call returns back to the saved context of `setjmp()`, and moving to the `else` case means that `a` had not been initialized.

When compiled with GCC with optimizations, the above function outputs:

```
a = 7 (initialized)
a = 1 (not initialized)
```

If you want this behavior without optimizations enabled, try adding the `register` storage class to `a`'s declaration.

[A demo.](http://ideone.com/3o59Mq)

## A longer explanation

So, why did I think `setjmp()` and `longjmp()` would work? This is what C.11 §7.13 ¶1-2 has to say about it:

> The header `<setjmp.h>` defines the macro `setjmp`, and declares one function and
>   one type, for bypassing the normal function call and return discipline.
>
> The type declared is
>
> `jmp_buf`
>
> which is an array type suitable for holding the information needed to restore a calling
>   environment. **The environment of a call to the `setjmp` macro consists of information
>   sufficient for a call to the `longjmp` function to return execution to the correct block and
>   invocation of that block, were it called recursively.** It does not include the state of the
>   floating-point status flags, of open files, or of any other component of the abstract
>   machine.

This explains that what is supposed to happen is that a `longjmp` back to the context saved in the `jmp_buf` by a call to `setjmp` will act as if the code that ran up until the `longjmp` call was a recursive function call, the the `longjmp` acts like a return from that recursive call back the `setjmp`. To me, this implies that the automatic variable would be "uninitialized".

```
    int a;

    // the following expression will be false if returning from `longjmp`
    if (setjmp(jb) == 0) {
        // this section of code can be treated like the `setjmp` call induced
        // a recursive call on this function that led to the execution of the
        // code in this body
        a = 7;
        //...
        // assuming not other code modified `jb`, the following call will
        // jump back to the `if` check above, but will behave like a recursive
        // function call had returned
        longjmp(jb, 1);
    } else {
        // `a` expected to be uninitialized here
    }
```

But, there seems to be a catch. From C.11 §7.13.2 ¶3:

> All accessible objects have values, and all other components of the abstract machine
>   have state, as of the time the `longjmp` function was called, except that **the values of
>   objects of automatic storage duration** that are local to the function containing the
>   invocation of the corresponding `setjmp` macro that do not have volatile-qualified type
>   and have been changed between the `setjmp` invocation and `longjmp` call **are
>   indeterminate**.

Since `a` is local, is not volatile-qualified, and has been changed between `setjmp` and `longjmp` calls, its value is indeterminate, ***even if it was properly initialized before calling `setjmp`***!

So, using `longjmp` back to a local `setjmp` after an automatic non-volatile variable has been modified will always result in making those modified variables "uninitialized" after returning to the point of the `setjmp`.

Comment: +1 for finding a solution to something that seemed impossible.

Comment: @jxh Amazing :) Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I am very confused that `a` has `indeterminate` value? does it means read `a` will result UB?

Comment: @BryanChen: Yes, that seems to be what the standard is saying. To avoid undefined behavior, automatic variables should be made `volatile`.

Answer (score 6):

You can emulate this using [`boost::optional<T>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html):

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

int main()
{   
    boost::optional<int> a;
    a = 7;

    std::cout << a.is_initialized() << std::endl; // true

    a.reset(); // "un-initialize"

    std::cout << a.is_initialized() << std::endl; // false
}
```

Comment: This is also a very good solution, however it's using a C++ class that was designed exactly for this, so it's not really what I was looking for. Regardless of it, the +1 is granted :)

Answer (score 0):

I am curious why you want to do that. However did you try following:

```
void some_fun() {
   int a;
   int b = a;  // Hoping compiler does not discard this.

   a = 7;

   // do something
   a = b;
}
```

Comment: That is *undefined behaviour* (reading from an uninitialized object.)

Comment: I know it is undefined, but isn't fritzone trying to achieve the same ?

Comment: No, they want to know if you can uninitialize a variable.

Comment: And is that 'uninitialized' value defined (to have some characteristic) ?

Comment: Invoking undefined behaviour can't be said to uninitialize a variable. It can't be said to achieve anything, because the program is invalid.

Comment: The characteristic OP wants is likely the ability for static analysis tools to report it.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is along the lines of:

```
int a, olda;
memcpy(&olda, &a, sizeof(a));

a = 7;
//...

memcpy(&a, &olda, sizeof(a));
// a is "uninitialized"
```

This avoids the trap representation issues of using assignment, relying on the fact that `char` does not have any trap representations. It also benefits from being vastly simpler than using `setjmp()` and `longjmp()`.