# How to warn not to use a variable after some point in g++/clang++?

Tags: c++

```cpp
MyContainer a = ...;
a.myDeallocate();
a[0] = 3;       // This will crash
```

Given a C++ code snippet that looks like the above one, I would like to make the C++ compiler (either g++ or clang++) raise a warning saying that `a` must not be used after its deallocation, possibly by inserting a custom code:

```cpp
MyContainer a = ...;
a.myDeallocate();
__should_not_use__(a); // If I put this code
a[0] = 3;              // The compiler will raise a warning at this point, hopefully.
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Related to [is-there-a-way-to-set-a-variable-as-uninitialized-in-gcc-clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745981/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-variable-as-uninitialized-in-gcc-clang).

Comment: Don't do that..

Answer (score 1):

You should get back to the principles and use RAII properly:

0. The aquired resource is memory.
1. Put the allocation in constructor.
2. Put the deallocation in destructor:

```
MyContainer::~MyContainer(){
    deallocate();
};
```

3. Adopt the rule of 0/3/5.
4. Manage the lifetime with proper scoping:

```
{   MyContainer a {/*...*/};
    /* Use 'a' */
};  // 'a' is out of scope now.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible at compile-time, since the deallocation may be conditioned on some user input not known at compile-time.

Assuming you have implemented `operator[]` for random access to elements in your container, a common practice is to use `assert`:

```cpp
#include <cassert>

class MyContainer {
    // ...
    Type operator[](int i) {
        assert (0 <= i && i < this->size());
        // ...
    }
};
```

Of course, you need to maintain the size of the container for this to work.

If out-of-bound indexing happens, this raises an AssertionError at runtime, but not at compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to generate a warning or error for this sort of thing at compile-time; the best you could do is a run-time check (and then throw an exception or `abort()` the program if `myDeallocate()` had previously been called)

If possible, the preferred approach is to do the `myDeallocate()` code only in `MyContainer`'s destructor.  Then your code can look like this:

```
{
   MyContainer a = ...;
}  // deallocation happens implicitly here

a[0] = 3; // causes compile-time error; run-time bug avoided
```